# Vlookup can't find a value that comes from a formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made a stock portfolio in google sheets and I want to lookup the biggest gains and smallest gain/loss for the day. I used the formula `=max(range)` to get the biggest gain, so far so good. However, I also want to find out which stock this is, for this I used the formula `=vlookup(the value from the =max formula,range,column,true` however the outcome is `#N/A` because it can not find the value that comes from the =max formula.

[picture of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUpEw.png)
[picture of what it should lookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH0cg.png)

I've tried to use different formula's but those are not applicable for what I'm trying to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=xlookup(H6, Portfolio!Q3:Q27, Portfolio!A3:A27, )
```